# PHP array references; holding references in an array for later use

Tags: php, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference, method-chaining

I'm trying to hold onto a variable reference for later use.

Not certain this is even possible, but I'm hoping I can initialize an array element, and reference it with a variable. Then, set the value of said array element to something, therefore making the value accessible from the referenced variable.

For example, this works:

```
class Test{

    private $_vars = array();

    public function bind($key, &$var){
        $this->_vars[$key] = &$var;
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch($key, &$var){
        $var = $this->_vars[$key];
        return $this;
    }

}

$test = new Test();
$string_set = 'This is a string';

$test->bind('string', $string_set)
    ->fetch('string', $string_get);

var_dump($string_get);
// expected:  string(16) "This is a string"
// actual:    string(16) "This is a string"
```

Now here's the problem; the ordering of method calls. I can't have the `call()` function returning a reference to `$this`, as the `call()` function needs to pass up the return value of the stored anonymous function (*otherwise I'd reorder the calls to be `->call()->fetch()` instead of `->fetch()->call()`*)

Anyways, the `fetch()` method should be setting the appropriate element by key in `$_vars` to `NULL` (*to empty any existing value, or initialize it, whichever*) and then referencing that element to the passed `$var`.

When the anonymous function is called (*after the `fetch()` binding is done*), it calls `bind()`, now binding the element in `$_vars` to whatever (*a `$string_set` containing `This is a string` in this case*) If my logic is correct, the `fetch()` bound variable (*`$string_get` in this case*) should now reference the array element in `$_vars` which is referencing `$string_set` which contains `This is a string`.

Doesn't seem that way though. Here's the code that's failing (*stripped down for brevity, but all the important parts are there*)

```
class Test{

    private $_vars = array();
    private $_function;

    public static function factory(){
        return $test = new self(function() use(&$test){
            $string_set = 'This is a string';
            $test->bind('string', $string_set);
            return true;
        });
    }

    private function __construct($function){
        $this->_function = $function;
    }

    public function bind($key, &$var){
        $this->_vars[$key] = &$var;
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch($key, &$var){
        $this->_vars[$key] = null;
        $var = &$this->_vars[$key]; // edited; was not assigning by reference
        return $this;
    }

    public function call(){
        return (bool) call_user_func($this->_function);
    }

}

$return = Test::factory()
    ->fetch('string', $string_get)
    ->call();

var_dump($return, $string_get);
// expected:  bool(TRUE), string(16) "This is a string"
// actual:    bool(TRUE), NULL
```

Am I chasing daisies here, is this even possible? Either way, I appreciate and thank you in advance for even glancing at this problem, any insight is really appreciated.

*Edit: the line in `fetch()` - `$var = $this->_vars[$key];` wasn't assigning the array element by reference. I've edited it now to `$var = &$this->_vars[$key];`, though it seemingly has no effect.*

***Bonus**: If this problem is solvable, that's obviously great; I'm actually hoping that `bind()` can take `$var` by value, rather than by reference. The method signature would be changed to something like `set($key, $value)`. Anyways, thanks again in advance.*

---

To elaborate for the seemingly curious (*looking in your direction @Tomalak*) I'll provide the more complete class, and usage scenario:

```
class Action{

    private static $_cache = array();
    private static $_basePath;

    private $_vars = array();
    private $_function;

    public static function setBasePath($basePath){
        $basePath = rtrim($basePath, '/') . '/';
        if(!is_dir($basePath)){
            // throw exception, $basePath not found
        }
        self::$_basePath = $basePath;
    }

    public static function load($actionPath){
        $actionPath = self::$_basePath . $actionPath;
        if(array_key_exists($actionPath, self::$_cache)){
            return self::$_cache[$actionPath];
        }
        if(!is_file($actionPath)){
            // throw exception, $actionPath not found
        }
        $action = call_user_func(function() use(&$action, $actionPath){
            return require($actionPath);
        });
        if(!($action instanceof self)){
            // throw exception, $action of invalid type
        }
        self::$_cache[$actionPath] = $action;
        return $action;
    }

    public function __construct($function){
        if(!is_callable($function)){
            // throw exception, $function not callable
        }
        $this->_function = $function;
    }

    public function bindReturn($key, &$var){
        $this->_vars[$key] = &$var;
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetchInto($key, &$var){
        $this->_vars[$key] = null;
        $var = &$this->_vars[$key];
        return $this;
    }

    public function run(){
        return (bool) call_user_func_array($this->_function, func_get_args());
    }

}

############################################################################

// actions/test.php

return new Action(function($name)
    use(&$action){

        if($name == 'Alice'){
            return false;
        }

        $data = "Hi, my name is {$name}.";
        $action->bindReturn('data', $data);

        return true;

    });

############################################################################

// index.php (or whatever)

$result = Action::load('actions/test.php') // loaded
    ->fetchInto('data', $data)
    ->run('Alice');

// Failed
echo $result
    ? 'Success - ' . $data
    : 'Failed';

$result = Action::load('actions/test.php') // called from cache
    ->fetchInto('data', $data)
    ->run('Bob');

// Success - Hi, my name is Bob
echo $result
    ? 'Success - ' . $data
    : 'Failed';
```

Comment: I don't understand why `fetch` needs to set anything to null. Maybe I'm just being daft.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Its because otherwise the index is not initialized to anything, and notices are thrown, because `call()` (*and subsequent functions*) have not yet bound values to the array.

Comment: The fact that `bind` happens under `call`, which calls a function that was passed into the constructor but not immediately invoked, is _completely confusing me_. This is very complex to parse; there must be a better way to achieve your wider goal.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Unfortunately no, there isn't a better way. I've excluded a great deal of logic associated with setting the anonymous function, etc., to isolate the actual issue and make it more comprehensible. I'm actually moving *away* from a complicated approach, in favor of this.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - To expand on my last comment, there isn't a better way that involves removing the anonymous function component of the process. However, if there exists a better way to manage the references, and their accessibility via the chained `fetch()` method (*or some permutation thereof*) I'd certainly be happy with that. I just need to be able to pass back an arbitrary number values from `call()` (*always at least one, that one being the `boolean` returned from `call()`*) but wrapping them in an array or object is the direction I'm moving *away* from.

Comment: It just seems to me that the API is counter-intuitive. I'd have to be very, _very_ sure before settling on this solution for anything. It's a vast design smell to me.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - It isn't as counter intuitive as you may believe; again, since I left out a great deal of code unrelated to this issue to isolate it, surely it seems peculiar. However, rest assured there is rhyme and reason to my approach, eccentric as it may in fact be.

Comment: If it only becomes clear when you _add_ complexity, then something is absolutely **definitely** wrong. A simple example may appear contrived but it should never be counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - The callbacks are loaded separately, wrapped in the class in question, as return values of included files. The `factory()` method takes a `$path` argument, loads/returns the object (*there is caching logic too, but we won't get into that*) and given the fluent interface, can be assigned references to populate with data (*the `fetch()` method*). The *actual* return value of the `call()` method (*which invokes the callback*) is merely a `boolean` (*possibly an `int` status code*) The status code can be tested for success, and the values used (*or discarded*) as necessary.

Comment: And what does all this accomplish?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Refer to edits :)

Comment: I'm asking for the _functional requirements_, not implementation details. What does this code _do_? Ultimately I think that you might have gotten stuck thinking about implementation details, and forgotten the options available at the highest level of design.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Its a handler, a part of a pseudo-MVC framework architecture, and this loosely translates to a (*sub-*) controller. They are used as event handlers (*observer-like functionality*) request handlers (*controllers/sub-controllers*) and procedures (*lower level operations like DB calls, mass-mailing, etc.*) I understand its, as I said before, a bit eccentric, perhaps even downright strange, however I've had success with my existing design/implementation, and I'm simply refactoring it.

Comment: Why not implement MVC the way everybody else does? :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Haha, I knew that was coming. Well yes, I could just use Zend or CodeIgniter, and I have. I don't want to use Zend or CodeIgniter though; I'm rolling my own, cause' that's how I roll. Besides, if everyone said "Ah, an abacus is fine by me." we wouldn't be having this conversation. (*seriously though, I'm not trying to make the next big thing, but I'm exploring different avenues of designing and implementing a HMVC-style framework, and so-far-so-good with version 1.0, I'm just trying to take it a few steps further. Also, I bet there were a lot of crappy next-gen abacuses.*)

Comment: I didn't say anything about bringing in an off-the-shelf framework. You can roll your own MVC framework without doing it in this bizarre fashion.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Oh I know, and I have. I'm just trying something new. Besides, at this point, if I wanted familiar MVC implementation, I would just go with an off-the-shelf framework, rather than roll my own.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak Geret'kal - As the ocean said to the dirt, I appreciate the *sediment* :P Really though, I'd be happy to get some feedback once it's out of alpha. I'll be linking up in my profile someday soon, the next time we cross on a question, I'll make mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want do is simply not possible (at least with referencces), because you cannot "redirect" a reference. Here's what happens:

```php
$instance->fetch('foo', $myVar);

public function fetch($key, &$var){
    // Here $var is a reference to $myVar.
    $var = &$this->_vars[$key]; // now $var is a reference to $this->_vars[$key]
                                // it is not connected to $myVar anymore.
}
```

Here's what you can do: You can pass `fetch()` a reference to an array and set an element in that array to be a reference to `$this->_vars[$key]` or you can pass `fetch()` an object and set a member variable to be the reference.

---

Oh, sry missed the obvious: You can of course just use your `bindReturn()` function in the use-case you presented. That would work without problems.

Comment: Thanks @Chronial - Thanks for your suggestion; so there isn't a way to point `$myVar` at `$this->_vars[$key]` without resorting to one of the workarounds you suggested? Also, what did you mean exactly regarding your edit about `bindReturn()`?

Comment: My goodness, I assume it was you meant, but `bindReturn()` is doing the job that `fetchInto()` should have been. By swapping the operands in the `fetchInto()` reference assignment, it works. I was overwriting my reference assignment, as your pre-edit answer had explained. My, what a silly error. Thanks again Chronial!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant ;). Just out of curiosity: What is the bindReturn() function supposed to do?

Comment: `bindReturn()` was intended to bind values from in the scope of the callback to an outside variable. Now that I've revised my design a bit, I realize that there are no circumstances under which "binding" a value to be returned provides any advantage, and simply returning by value is best. Furthermore, when binding values by reference, an intermediary variable is always necessary, so returning values directly from function calls is not possible. I'll update my answer with the more finalized version sometime a bit later. Check back if you want. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have problem with

```
public function fetch($key, &$var){
    $this->_vars[$key] = null;
    $var = $this->_vars[$key];
    return $this;
}
```

If you want to remove the key, don't set it to null, unset it:

Edit: changed the code to avoid uninitialized variable exception.

```
public function fetch($key, &$var){
    if(isset($this->_vars[$key]))
    {
        $var = $this->_vars[$key];
        unset($this->_vars[$key]);
    }
    else
    {
        $var = null;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: (*deleted my comment because I though I misread your answer, but it was the same in the end anyways*) Thanks @Dani - Unfortunately that doesn't work. Setting `NULL` instead of `unset()` does double duty, in that it empties the existing value, or initializes the array element. If I use `unset()`, notices get throw regarding the undefined index, since the values haven't been set by `call()` yet.

Comment: @Bracketworks: setting to null does *not* empty existing variable. it set the variable its referencing to null, the reference still holds. you can try to use isset (I'll edit the answer soon)

Comment: Ah, good point. However since the `fetch()` call is occurring before any variables are set, setting to `NULL` at that point shouldn't affect even the referenced variable's values (*nothing has been referenced via `bind()` yet*)